# ¿Qué evento tengo que usar?

Tags: c#, eventos

Tengo una aplicación de escritorio hecha en VisualStudio en C#.

En esta tabla se muestran los nombres de varios ficheros subidos a un servidor, y una columna con un Check para seleccionar cuales quieres descargar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando se abre la aplicación, todas las celdas aparecen desmarcadas y el botón de Descargar deshabilitado.

Quiero que **cuando se haga click en un checkbox** cambie la propiedad del botón en función de si hay algun checkbox seleccionado. Si no lo hay, volverse a deshabilitar.

He probado con el evento `CellClick`, `CellContentClick`, `CellValueChanged`... muchos. Pero cuando meto el código<sup>1</sup>, y hago click en el checkbox, hasta que no hago click en otra celda no se ejecuta el código.

¿**Qué evento he de usar** para que nada mas hacer click, sin tener que pulsar fuera o en otra celda, calcule el estado en el que tiene que estar el botón?

<sup>1</sup>Código:

```
bool guardar = false;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gvDocumentos.Rows)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[2].Value) == true)
            {
                guardar = true;
            }
        }
btnDescargar.enabled = guardar;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

has una prueba de la siguiente manera

En el constructor agrega los handlers para los eventos CellContentClick y CellValueChanged

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.dataGridView1.CellContentClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CellContentClick);
        this.dataGridView1.CellValueChanged += DataGridView1_CellValueChanged;
    }
```

Luego maneja los eventos de la siguiente manera:

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }

    private void DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var valor = (bool) dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;

        btnDescargar.Enabled = valor;
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte, el `Commit` lo solucionó!

Answer (score 2):

Prueba de la siguiente manera:

```
private void myDataGrid_OnCellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == columnaCheckbox.Index && e.RowIndex != -1)
    {
        // Cambia el estado del botón
    }
}
```

Y añadele este código para hacerle saber al `DataGridView` que ya has terminado de hacer cambios en el `CheckBox`:

```
private void myDataGrid_OnCellMouseUp(object sender,DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == columnaCheckbox.Index && e.RowIndex != -1)
    {
        dataGrid.EndEdit();
    }
}
```

[Referencia](https://web.archive.org/web/20200808100443/http://geekswithblogs.net/FrostRed/archive/2008/09/07/125001.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Probando con mi ejemplo (al que me trajiste desde mi consulta) jajaja estoy probando mientras espero si pueden ayudarme con mi duda y funciona en el primer clic cuando usas el evento:

```
CellMouseClick
```

Probalo y despues me contas... anda de maravillas !!! jajajaja y sin ningún codigo adicional

Comment: Es un codigo antiguo de otra empresa asi que ya no puedo probarlo (y armar una app para probar me da pereza xD ).  Aunque creo recordar que lo intenté.. Gracias igualemente

Comment: todo bien !!! pero es bueno tenerlo en cuenta: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellmouseclick(v=vs.110).aspx