# SelectionChanged en datagridview no se comporta como corresponde

Tags: vb.net, .net

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en VB.NET 2010 en la que tengo en un formulario, un datagridview que se llena de datos. Cuando completa la carga del DGV hago lo siguiente:

```
Me.DataGridView1.ClearSelection()
```

Debajo tengo una serie de textboxes, combos, etc. Resulta que cuando selecciono un item del DGV se llenan todos los controles, pero cuando hago el primer clic en el DGV no pasa nada, recién en el segundo clic se llenan los controles. 
Quiero aclarar que la lógica de toda la carga de los controles la tengo colocada en el **SelectionChanged** del DataGridView
Eso esta bien ? o debería colocarlo en otro evento del control del DataGridView ?

Comment: Me recuerda a [esta pregunta mia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/42518/15855). Será esa la respuesta que necesitas?

Comment: como te respondí por alla, el evento que hay que usar es el CellMouseClick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probando y probando llegue a la solución de que el evento que tengo que usar es el **CellMouseClick**

Comment: Podrías explicar un poco mas porque esa es la solución?

Comment: Y no olvides marcarla como respuesta aceptada para ayudar a otros usuarios con el mismo problema y asi ganar reputación en el sitio